# How can I insert a border outside my circular image?

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I insert a grey border outside an circular image.

I'm using this code to create circular imageviews:

```
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        } 

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
        BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }
```

I tried to insert the border using these lines:

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
```

But it didn't worked, the border appeared, but the image disappeared.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I couldn't understand your code, I'm not using a drawable image to load inside the imageview, I'm getting the image from an URL, using picasso. I'm having some problems trying to implement your code to mine, to load the image I use this line: load("URL).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(groupAvatar);

Comment: yes, i got you, mainly you can get bitmap from your image, then simple put you bitmap which i'm getting from drawable. Nothing so different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved as follows:

```
   //put your bitmap here 
             Bitmap mIcon11=    MainActivity.drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.crow)); 

              Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIcon11.getWidth(),
                        mIcon11.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

                final Rect itemRect = new Rect(0, 0, mIcon11.getWidth(), mIcon11.getHeight());


             RectF roundRect = new RectF(itemRect);
             Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  //your bitmap here  
             Bitmap bitmap = MainActivity.drawableToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.crow));

             mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
             mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             canvas.drawRoundRect(roundRect, 100, 100, mPaint);

             roundRect.set(itemRect.left + 5, itemRect.top + 5, itemRect.right - 5, itemRect.bottom - 5);
             Path clipPath = new Path();
            //roundness of border
             clipPath.addRoundRect(roundRect, 100, 100, Path.Direction.CW);
             canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);
             canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
             canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, roundRect, mPaint);
             canvas.restore();
             myImageView.setImageBitmap(output);
```