# android stroke over bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Hi i am merging to image my first image take shape of second image now i just want to draw a store over the final image but stroke should be in shape and not in square my code for bitmap are below

```
public Bitmap starShape(Bitmap original,Bitmap oldmask){
        Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(oldmask, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), false);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: there is stroke and border rounded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709237/how-can-i-insert-a-border-outside-my-circular-image/33709261#33709261

Comment: @Androider its making a round circle

Comment: yes, you can set the roundness as i leave a comment there,

Comment: @Androider but i want the shape of oldmask for example oldmask is heart with background transparent so i want a border over heart shape

Comment: means you want heart instead of circle?

Comment: let me explain i have 2 bitmap one is normal image and other is heart shape image red in color and rest part is transparent background i am merging two image . my first image take the shape of second image now i want to draw a stroke after the second image take shape of first image